# Arena design for events in Terraria

Tags: terraria

I would like to ask how can an Arena be built to maximise the amount of kills (especially of Stronger Mobs) for timed events like Frost Moon and Pumpkins Moon. Since these events last only for the night, killing faster is the most important factor to get more loots.

I usually use a generic boss fighting Arena, multiple layers of platform about 6-12 tiles apart with al least 300 tiles wide just above ground with full campfire and lantern coverage, but there are a few problems faced:

1. There are little cover from Frost Queen's hail of icicles
2. Towards later waves, weaker mobs still roam around distracting against fighting stronger mobs like Frost Queen and Pumpking
3. Straight platforms does not help dodging Santa's machine gun

For the purpose of this question, assume only all items before the Lunar events are available.

Even though I asked for Frost Moon and Pumpkin Moon events, please feel free to suggest Arenas that works for other Events such as Pirate or Martian events.

Answer (score -1):

Create an arena with a lot of areas for enemies to spawn. Rows of long platforms, that go off the edge of the screen are best. Try to keep it away from caves, and other things that can get filled up with enemies. Obviously, also use a water candle and battle potion. Create a small box of shelter, or a covered minecart going side to side. Use a weapon like a storm bow, and you should be good.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little about "a small box of shelter"? Cos if I just place random blocks around, it kinda block me more than Frost Queen's attacks

Answer (score -2):

I never really used arenas, but these are some suggestions.
**1**(Frost queen's icicles): You can put opened doors/trapdoors around the arena and close them when the icicles are used. Although on that case I would recommend the Ice Staff (the one that places temporary ice blocks.)
**2**(normal mobs getting in the way)Maybe make the arena in the air or use a Peace Candle (that might get in the way of the minibosses though)
**3**(Santa attacks)Try getting a black belt or the Eye Of Cthulhu shield, the Ice staff also works in this situation.

That's all the suggestions, I hope you make use of these and find an answer.

Comment: Ice staff is a tactical weapon but the dps is low compared to other equipments I can obtain prior to these events. I am asking for ideas/designs that helps kill faster, helping in survivability is secondary.